# How to animate webp image in android

Tags: android, webp

I have used one webp image url in my app via glide and set it to image view but the image which is an animated one is not getting animated. Image is showing up but not getting animated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this library to animate webp file:
[GlideWebpDecoder](https://github.com/zjupure/GlideWebpDecoder)